# Eureka not registering various services/zuul on ec2 via docker deploy, but allowing registration of services fine on local machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, netflix-eureka

I've looked at several other posts, to no avail, I am simply trying to deploy an ec2 instance via docker, and register various services/zuul to it. Important, i am running the services/ eureka client on seperate containers via docker. 
Yes I can view Eureka client page via internet after deploying with docker, and it shows no instances. I will show the side by side comparison of logs local via on docker, along with my dockerfiles. I've had other friends of mine that have had no issue using similar application.yml and pom.xml configurations/main application class configurations.

**STACKTRACE ISSUE:**

LEFT SIDE: REGISTERING ZUUL ON EC2 ***NOT WORKING***

RIGHT SIDE: REGISTERING ZUUL ON LOCAL HOST ***WORKING GREAT***
[image]

Eureka main application class/application.yml

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service-fm
server:
  port: 8761  
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Gateway main/application.yml

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service-fm
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
```

This seems to be a challenging space, as most of the answers to similar questions have not been fulfilled throughout stack overflow, so I appreciate the attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the snippets that you've provided and the scenario explained, the following are my assumptions.

1. You're not explicitly specifying the eureka server address. Because of this, it's taking default address http://localhost:8761 (default behavior)
2. Since you can view the eureka web console you are binding the containers port with host port (both 8761) and accessing eureka console using http://server_ip_or_domain:8761/ (you're doing the same for other containers as well)
3. You're not using any docker orchestration tool instead, you are just running the docker individually in an EC2 VM

**Cause of this issue**

Based on these assumptions, I can find when running in a container your discovery client applications(services/zuul) are trying to access the localhost of that container, not your hosts since you are not explicitly specifying any other eureka URL and because of this, it couldn't find the eureka server in that same container.

> The point is, containers have their own localhost and when you're
>   referring to localhost from a container this doesn't mean that you are
>   referring to the localhost of the host machine. Instead, your request is still trying to access the localhost of the container. (Imagine this as same as your
>   application running on a VM)

**Solution**

You can specify the discovery server URL in your `application.yml`. Not localhost URL. you can use the IP or domain of the VM or the same address you are using for accessing your eureka web console.

For managing both environments you can use spring profiles or use an environment variable to set these kinds of environment-specific properties.

And if you really don't like to see your request go out of your machine and coming back you can think about docker DNS. i.e when using docker you can use a friendly DNS rather than an IP. For achieving this run all your containers in the same docker network and then you can refer the containers to each other via their container name or hostname.